# Boot Pi4 using GPIO of Pi0

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4, power, pi-zero

I am trying using Pi Zero GPIO and optocoupler to Power On(boot) my Pi4. My Pi4 is shutdown with terminal command(It is connected with power).

My schematic set up:

[image: Set up]

My Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
print "POWER on"
GPIO.output(23,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
print "POWER off"
GPIO.output(23,GPIO.LOW)
```

What i am doing wrong and it is not working? If i connect GPIO 5 and 6 of my Pi4 it is booting.

Comment: Have you tested the individual parts of the circuit(s)?  GPIO 3 (pin 5) has a 1k8 pull-up to 3V3.  Will a 1k pull to ground be enough?

Comment: @joan No, I am newbie in pi and GPIO. schematic is correct. I think is the python code, which i read and made it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a 1kΩ resistor you can't pull the pin LOW. You will get ~1.2V which is HIGH.

Just get rid of it or reduce to 100Ω.

There is no need for a resistor; it is a protection mechanism to prevent excessive current for an unlikely combination of circumstances.

An opto-isolator would never be capable of pulling enough current to cause problems.

Comment: First test, it is working. Remove 1K. You mean to replace it with 100ohm or remove it? What is better? The 270ohm is fine?

Comment: It is a simple calculation. You need to pull the pin below 0.8V. There is no need for any resistor.